# How to get data from a multidimensional PSafeArray?

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-7, safearray

I need to read data from a `PSafeArray` in Delphi.
That `PSafeArray` is returned by a method implemented in a DLL developed in C#. This method returns a two dimensional string array `string[,]`. How to read such `PSafeArray` result in Delphi ?

Answer (score 6):

You must use the [`SafeArrayGetLBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`SafeArrayGetUBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`SafeArrayGetElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221255%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

Try this sample

```
var
  LSafeArray: PSafeArray;
  LBound, UBound, I: LongInt;
  LYBound, UYBound, J: LongInt;
  Index: array [0..1] of Integer;
  LData: OleVariant;
begin
  //get the PSafeArray
  LSafeArray := GetArray;// GetArray is your own function
  //get the bounds of the first dimension
  SafeArrayGetLBound(LSafeArray, 1, LBound);
  SafeArrayGetUBound(LSafeArray, 1, UBound);
  //get the bounds of the second dimension
  SafeArrayGetLBound(LSafeArray, 2, LYBound);
  SafeArrayGetUBound(LSafeArray, 2, UYBound);

  //iterate over the array  
  for I := LBound to UBound do
   for J := LYBound to UYBound do
    begin
      //set the index of the element to get
      Index[0]:=I; 
      Index[1]:=J;
      SafeArrayGetElement(LSafeArray, Index, LData);

      //do something with the data  
      Memo1.Lines.Add(LData);
    end;
  SafeArrayDestroy(LSafeArray);
end;
```